# MYSQL query to Update the field if found duplicates?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my problem. I got a table `Meaning`

```
ID - Meaning
1 - red car
2 - cat man
3 - red car
4 - ontime
5 - red car
....
```

I want to make the colum `Meaning` become Unique. So i want to build a query to found all the duplicates & for each of duplicate, the system should append `[number]` to make the cell become unique.

So after running that query, the result should be:

```
ID - Meaning
1 - red car
2 - cat man
3 - red car [2]
4 - ontime
5 - red car [3]
....
```

The table is pretty long about 100K rows. The query could be similar to this query

```
Update Table Meaning set meaning=concat(meaning,"1") 
where meaning in (select meaning from Meaning group by meaning having count(meaning>1)
```

So what is the query for solving the problem?

Seem we have to use `set variable` to check each row?

Comment: Why don't you make the column UNIQUE in the first place?

Comment: I took data from other source, that is the problem

Comment: @cen, that might not be possible unless he makes the records unique first.

Comment: i will make Record unique later affter there is no duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

step 1: create temporary table

```
CREATE TABLE TMP (id int, meaning varchar (2));
```

step 2: prepare query and insert into temporary table

```
insert into tmp 
SELECT id, 
CASE WHEN cnt =0 theN meaning ELSE concat(meaning,'[',cnt+1,']') END AS meaning 

FROM
(
SELECT t1.id, t1.meaning, (

SELECT COUNT( t.id ) 
FROM test t
where  t.meaning=t1.meaning 
and t.id<t1.id
) as cnt
FROM test t1
)TMP
```

step 3

```
truncate table test
```

step 4: migrate to original

```
insert into test select * from tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.*
     , CONCAT(x.meaning,CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN '' ELSE COUNT(*) END) meaning 
  FROM meanings 
     x JOIN meanings 
     y ON y.meaning = x.meaning 
   AND y.id <= x.id 
 GROUP 
    BY id;
```

Comment: thax for ur answer, but i need UPDATE. can u provide UPDATE Query?